# Deploy both SPA and functions with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have a react app, that consumes a firebase (firestore) backend.
I also use firebase hosting for hosting the SPA. My firebase.json:

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "/",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      },
      {
        "source": "/app/**",
        "function": "app"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "functions": {
    "source": "functions",
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ]
  }
}
```

So now I tested some functions and I want to deploy them. (I have a `functions` dir which contains package.json, node_modules, and index.js which contains the functions) If I simply run `firebase deploy`, it will only deploy the build from the build folder.

My questions are:

- Can I deploy both a SPA and functions using the same firebase project?
- If so, what am I doing wrong?

  - How do I specify the port at which I want to run the functions?
  - Or should I use routing params or something else?

Comment: Can you show your Firebase project file structure? "If I simply run firebase deploy, it will only deploy the build from the build folder." => Are you sure your functions are not deployed? How do you confirm that?

Comment: Your firebase.json isn't showing a "functions" configuration (only "hosting"), so no Cloud Functions code will be deployed.  I think you're assuming something is going to happen when it's not configured to do so.  When you deploy to Firebase Hosting, nothing happen in Cloud Functions.  They are not that tightly integrated.  They are still separate products with separate configurations that need to be configured and deployed independently.

Comment: @DougStevenson If I am not mistaking you don't need a `functions` configuration in the `firebase.json` file to be able to deploy Cloud Functions. Only if you want to specify another folder than the default `functions` one (or some `predeploy` options) you would add a `functions` configuration.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec You definitely need a functions configuration for deployment.  How else would the CLI know what you want to do?

Comment: @DougStevenson Doug, sorry to insist, I had checked before writing the above comment: most of my projects (with functions) don't have a `functions` configuration in the `firebase.json` and I've just double-checked with a brand new project and I confirm this point. I agree it seems strange...

Comment: @RenaudTarnec You don't need a functions config to **have** or **use** functions in your project.  You just need one to **deploy** functions.  It's a non-negotiable requirement. I can guarantee you that if you don't have a functions config in your firebase.json, you will not be able to deploy functions from that project space.  `firebase deploy` will not see or deploy any functions, and `firebase deploy --only functions` will simply fail.

Comment: @DougStevenson Well, I can just confirm again that I have no problem to deploy Cloud Functions with the CLI (`firebase deploy` or `firebase deploy --only functions`) in a project that doesn't have a `functions` node/configuration in the `firebase.json` file. Also, if you create a brand new Firebase project with the CLI, selecting Cloud Functions (among other services), the `firebase.json` default file generated by the CLI doesn't contain a `functions` node/configuration and you can deploy Cloud Functions with the CLI.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec When I run with `--only functions`, I get an error "Error: Cannot understand what targets to deploy/serve. No targets in firebase.json match '--only functions'."

Comment: @RenaudTarnec After some experimenting, here's the deal. The Firebase CLI used to always add a functions config, but it no longer does.  It will not add a config for JavaScript projects that *do not* choose ESLint, and instead take silent defaults (which I find confusing).  However, for TypeScript projects, it *will always* add a default config, which is required for hooking the build phase.  At this point, I'm thinking of filing a bug for the missing config in the one specific case, because I'm sure it didn't used to behave like that.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks. In my case, it might be a more simple mistake I'm making in my firebase.json (ie the rewrites?). I'm configuring to host the 'build' folder (which I use to build the react production code), but my functions are in the 'functions' folder.

Comment: Just to be clear - my goal is to deploy both the SPA and the functions from within the same code base and to the same firebase project.

Comment: You should just be able to `firebase deploy` to deploy everything in your project space at the same time.  I can't really see what you're doing wrong.  You might want to edit the question to show the output from the CLI, and the specific code that isn't working the way you expect.  There are a lot of moving parts, and you'll need to narrow it down.

Comment: My CLI feedback shows no errors - both hosting and functions are deployed. Now when I hit the production url - I either get the website or a firebase 404 page. What I want to happen, is to fallback to /index.html, except for all paths that start with /api/** or /app/** => I want them to hit the functions endpoint(s). This part seems to be going wrong.